# How to manipulate toggles states using ngModel in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8, angular-ngmodel

community. I am getting an object like this
[image]

in which values are for my toggles: `isCashbookAc, isCustomer, isOnOff, isPfa, isSupplier`

Here is my toggles

[image]

it is showing on popup which is opening by clicking on edit icon of mat table. Based on these values (isCashbookAc,isCustomer) i want my toggles can enable or disable automatically. For this i am using `ngModel` because it is dynamic

Here is my code:

> .html

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="100px">
            <mat-grid-tile class="ml-1 mr-1" *ngFor="let companyToggle of companyToggleArr; let i = index">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                    <mat-label style="margin-right: 20px">{{labels[i]}}</mat-label>
                    <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="companyToggle.status" name="{{'name' + i}}"></mat-slide-toggle>
                </div>
            </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
```

> .ts

```
checkForUpdate(): void {
        console.log(this.updateData) //above image of object is from t
        if (this.updateData) {
            this.itemForm.patchValue({
                name: this.updateData.company.name,
                city: this.updateData.company.city,
                address: this.updateData.company.address,
                state: this.updateData.company.state,
                country: this.updateData.company.country,
                phone: this.updateData.company.phone,
                email: this.updateData.company.email,
                website: this.updateData.company.website,
                isActive: this.updateData.company.isActive,            
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to toggle enable to disable based on object values of it isCashbookAc, isCustomer, isOnOff, isPfa, isSupplier

Comment: Can you create stackblitz of your code.

Comment: @surendrakumar i sent you chat request please check